# Sine Series: ONB

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

How to show that $\{\sin{kx}:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ for $\{f\in\mathcal{L}^2[0,\pi]:f(0)=f(\pi)=0\}$ is an ONB?

(Clearly they are orthogonal to each other but is their span also dense?)

What general route can one follow when one wants to check total?

Comment: They aren't dense. Do you mean the linear combinations of these functions are dense there?

Comment: Yes that is sloppy, more precise would be is their linear hull dense or in short are they total... Thanks for your note anyway!!!

Comment: As it stands now, your question is inaccurate, and clarifications in comments do not count. Make your question what you want to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: There is no such thing as a boundary condition $f(0)=0$ or $f(\pi)=0$ on $L^{2}[0,\pi]$. Functions in $L^{2}[0,\pi]$ are equivalence classes of functions which are equal to each other a.e.. That part should be tossed out of your question. What is true is that
$$\left\{ \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sin(nx)\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$$
is a complete orthonormal basis of $L^{2}[0,\pi]$. There are no conditions required for the $\sin$ series of $f \in L^{2}[0,\pi]$ to converges to $f$ in $L^{2}[0,\pi]$.

To prove this, start with the fact that $\{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{inx}\}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$ is a complete orthonormal basis of $L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]$. Every $f \in L^{2}[0,\pi]$ has an odd extension to $\tilde{f}$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$. That is $\tilde{f}(x)=-f(-x)$ for $-\pi \le x < 0$ and $\tilde{f}(x)=f(x)$ for $0 \le x \le \pi$. then
$$
\begin{align}
     \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\tilde{f}(x)e^{-inx}\,dx 
         & = -\int_{-\pi}^{0}f(-x)e^{-inx}\,dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}\,dx \\
         & = -\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)e^{inx}\,dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}\,dx \\
         & = -2i\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(nx)\,dx .
\end{align}
$$
Therefore the following converges in $L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]$:
$$
       \tilde{f} = -\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2i}{2\pi}
                               \left(\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x')\sin(nx')\,dx'\right)e^{inx}.
$$
Because $\tilde{f}$ is odd, then the following converges in $L^{2}[0,\pi]$:
$$
    f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\tilde{f}(x)-\tilde{f}(-x)\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
          \left(\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x')\sin(nx')\,dx'\right)\sin(nx).
$$
And that's the result you want.

Comment: Perhaps one way to interpret his question is that the underlying space should be the $L^2$ closure of all continuous functions vanishing on the boundary.

Comment: @Christopher : "the L2 closure of all continuous functions vanishing on the boundary" includes $\{ \sin kx\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ and is $L^{2}$.

Comment: @Christopher: I'm sure many people have been confused by how such general convergence could occur. If it doesn't bother you at first glance, you're not thinking about it. Fourier gave the sin series for cos and showed that it converged except at the endpoints. You know, that had to be disturbing at the time; it was one of the objections against his general assertions. It's strange that $1$ can be expanded in a sin series. It's like asserting that odd powers of $x$ could converge to even powers on an interval.

Comment: Ah, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, if you want to avoid any Fourier series methods: first throw in the function $1$ into your set $\{\sin{kx}\}$. The resulting linear span is a subalgebra of $C(T,\mathbb{R})$, where $T$ is the one-dimensional torus. Then apply Stone-Weierstrass to obtain density in the $C$-norm. Now use the fact that $C(T,\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^2(T, \mathbb{R})$ in the $L^2$ norm. Since $T$ is compact, one can control the $L^2$ norm by the $C$-norm, which shows that the subalgebra generated by $1, \{\sin{kx}\}$ is dense in $L^2(T)$. Then remove the constants.